# Facing problem while using Title bar?

Tags: android, titlebar

I am trying to insert a title bar with the following code. I try to keep the two buttons on it at left most and right most ends. But the buttons are not visible on the titlebar.
TextView is used as a title bar here and that is :

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:text="CAMERA"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#4C7D7E"
>
</TextView>
```

code for buttons:

<

```
Button
android:id="@+id/save"
android:layout_width="144px"
android:layout_height="37px"
android:text="save"
android:layout_x="7px"
android:layout_y="388px"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/send"
android:layout_width="144px"
android:layout_height="37px"
android:text="send"

android:layout_x="158px"
android:layout_y="388px"
>
</Button>
```

Cant guess.Can any one help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no "following code" in your question.

Comment: <TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:text="textview"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#4C7D7E"
>
</TextView>

Comment: and the code for buttons are:

Comment: <Button
android:id="@+id/save"
android:layout_width="144px"
android:layout_height="37px"
android:text="save"
android:layout_x="7px"
android:layout_y="388px"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/send"
android:layout_width="144px"
android:layout_height="37px"
android:text="send"

android:layout_x="158px"
android:layout_y="388px"
>
</Button>

Comment: You could add the codes to your question. There is an edit option.

Comment: Its preferable to use "dip" or "dp" instead of "px".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a layout like this and set it as title bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <Button
         android:id="@+id/save"
         android:layout_width="144px"
         android:layout_height="37px"
         android:text="save"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:text="right" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="144px"
        android:layout_height="37px"
        android:text="send"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the code.But when am trying to add color to the title bar in the same code which you have suggested and making it fill_parent. it is not working

Comment: As am using textview as a title bar then the textview should be fill_parent where i want to place the button on it.

Comment: You want the text to go below the buttons?

Comment: Use relativeLayout instead of linear.

Answer (score 0):

What type of parent do these items reside in? Personally, I would probably use a TableLayout and then use gravity to position the objects where I wanted them to appear. Use the weight tag to set the spacing for the objects on the titleBar.

Comment: am using fill parent to textview and i want the button to be on the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Use This and tell me is this work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/titlebar" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:weightSum="3"> 
            <Button 
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:id="@+id/save" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:text="save"/> 

            <TextView 
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/titleText" 
            android:text="right" /> 

            <Button 
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/send" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="send" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ya. i need the upperlayer i.e. the textview with the color which fill the from the left to the right and button on it. when am trying to that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/main_bg">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Rel_Top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4C7D7E">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Btn_Back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:background="@drawable/settings"/>


        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/Text_Title"
        android:text="Title"  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/Btn_Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:background="@drawable/search" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
If you want to change the background color then change the background color in <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Rel_Top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#4C7D7E">
```